# " TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String " during knife bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

When I am using the knife bootstrap command to connect the node to the chef server I am facing this issue.

> Doing old-style registration with the validation key at ...
>       Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead
>
> Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx ( some IP address )
>       ERROR: TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

When I searched in google I got the few answers regarding to the " Doing old-style registration with the validation key at ..." but I saw some location in "..." in above that line.

I don't know what wrong I am doing.

***Chef Information:***
I used GCP for the workstation, node and for the server I used `"manage.chef.io"` ( chef server )

> ## NOTE : please see the comment below

When I executed this command :

```
knife bootstrap 35.XX.xx.x --ssh-user USER-NAME --sudo --identity-file SSH-FILE-LOCATION -N node1 -VV
```

I am getting this :

```
INFO: Using configuration from /home/sandeep.nayak/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb
Doing old-style registration with the validation key at ...
Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead

Connecting to 35.200.203.207
Traceback (most recent call last):
        16: from /usr/bin/knife:75:in `<main>'
        15: from /usr/bin/knife:75:in `load'
        14: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/bin/knife:24:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:161:in `run'
        12: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife.rb:220:in `run'
        11: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife.rb:441:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        10: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
         9: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife.rb:442:in `block in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
         8: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:391:in `run'
         7: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:426:in `knife_ssh'
         6: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:448:in `ssh_command'
         5: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap.rb:354:in `render_template'
         4: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `evaluate'
         3: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `instance_eval'
         2: from (erubis):196:in `block in evaluate'
         1: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/core/bootstrap_context.rb:49:in `validation_key'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/core/bootstrap_context.rb:49:in `expand_path': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

My knife.rb file :

```
# See http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife configuration options

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "techrealm"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/techrealm.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/techrealm"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

There are few I have noticed when I try to solving this issue:

1. Initially, I am unable to see the file called "validation.pem" at /etc/chef in workstation ( I dont know where validation.pem file is present ( workstation or node )). So I tried

   knife configure client /etc/chef
   It created the two files *1. client.pem* *2. validation.pem* but validation.pem file is empty.
2. I am seeing some ruby line at

> default(:validation_key) 
>       { chef_zero.enabled ? nil : platform_specific_path("/etc/chef/techrealm.pem") }

at this location " opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-config-14.3.37/lib/chef-config/config.rb"

Hope this will help you

Comment: Please run with `--verbose --verbose --verbose` to get a stack trace.

Comment: I executed this command " knife bootstrap 35.xx --ssh-user USER --sudo --identity-file SSH-KEY -N node1 -VV "
I got this " 1: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/core/bootstrap_context.rb:49:in `validation_key'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.3.37/lib/chef/knife/core/bootstrap_context.rb:49:in `expand_path': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError) "

Comment: Add the error into your question, comments don't allow formatting. And please show the full stack trace, not just one line of it.

Comment: Please read the error Information in the Question description @coderanger

Comment: What's in your `knife.rb` config file? It sounds like you explicitly set `validation_key nil` or similar?

Comment: So, where can I edit to overcome this error, actually I tried something please see in the question description